# Найти, выбрать и убрать дубликаты в pl/sql

Tags: plsql, plsql-developer

Необходимо в строке найти слово "ГГБ" и показать результат , убирая дубликаты

Строки с данными

```
;;;ГГБ62252ЦДБ62252ГГБ62251Г-ка162252ГГБ62252Г-ка462252Г-ка562252Г-ка662252Г-ка762252Г-ка862252Г-ка962252Г-ка1062252
```

и

```
;;;ГГБ62252ЦДБ62252ГГБ62252Г-ка162252ГГБ62252Г-ка462252Г-ка562252Г-ка662252Г-ка762252Г-ка862252Г
```

Таблица
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат необходимо такой(без дубликатов). Результат данного варианта предпочтителен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример выполнения той же задачи на MySQL - используется рекурсивный CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 (value) AS (
  SELECT ';;;ГГБ62252ЦДБ62252ГГБ62251Г-ка162252ГГБ62252Г-ка462252Г-ка562252Г-ка662252Г-ка762252Г-ка862252Г-ка962252Г-ка1062252'
),
cte2 (occurence, value) AS (
  SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value,
                       'ГГБ\\d+'),
         REPLACE(value,
                 REGEXP_SUBSTR(value,
                               'ГГБ\\d+'), 
                 ',')
  FROM cte1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value,
                       'ГГБ\\d+'),
         REPLACE(value,
                 REGEXP_SUBSTR(value,
                               'ГГБ\\d+'), 
                 ',')
  FROM cte2
  WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(value,
                      'ГГБ\\d+') IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT occurence
FROM cte2
```

| occurence |
| --- |
| ГГБ62252 |
| ГГБ62251 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AavqOUEx)

Превращать это в код, который понимает Oracle, с учётом его совершенно невменяемых сообщений - без меня...

PS. Также код предполагает, что соответствующее шаблону значение не может являться подстрокой другого значения (ГГБ62252 и ГГБ622520, например). При невыполнении это условия код будет работать неправильно.

Comment: Немного уточнил вопрос. Т.е. если есть идентиф. номер то будет вывод в данном случае уже в две строки с одним идентификатором. Тогда можете поправить ответ,  вместо данных  ';;;ГГБ62252ЦДБ62252ГГБ62251Г...' указав поля таблицы.

Comment: @wq55 Ну обратное агрегирование как бы вообще не проблема.